# Putting Checkbox values into an array using CSHTML

Tags: razor, asp.net-webpages

How can I take the values checked in my check boxes and put them into an array, using Razor Webpages?

```
<div>
                    <label for="mon">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="mon" name="day[]" value="monday" @(Request.Form["day"] == "mon" ? "checked" : "")>Monday
                    </label>
                    <label for="tue">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="tue" name="day[]" value="tuesday" @(Request.Form["day"] == "tue" ? "checked" : "")>Tuesday
                    </label>
                    <label for="wed">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="wed" name="day[]" value="wednesday" @(Request.Form["day"] == "wed" ? "checked" : "")>Wednesday
                    </label>
                    <label for="thur">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="thur" name="day[]" value="thursday" @(Request.Form["day"] == "thur" ? "checked" : "")>Thursday
                    </label>
                    <label for="fri">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="fri" name="day[]" value="friday" @(Request.Form["day"] == "fri" ? "checked" : "")>Friday
                    </label>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to use a model in the view then you can map the properties for posting. I would use a bool for each day. Something like:

Your class:

```
public class MyModel {

public bool Monday {get;set;}
public bool Tuesday {get;set} 

etc....
```

}

Add this to the top of your view

```
@model MyModel
```

and your form

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()){
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m=>m.Monday)
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m=>m.Tuesday)
etc..
}
```

and In your controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult YourViewName(MyModel model){
```

You can get these values in your action like

```
var mondayChecked = model.Monday;
```

Comment: There are no models in ASP.NET Web Pages.

Answer (score 0):

Using the code you already have, the values will be available in the `Request.Form` collection as `Request.Form["day[]"]`. They will be a comma separated string. You can convert that to an array using `string.Split()`:

```
var myArrayOfDays = Request.Form["day[]"].Split(new [] {','});
```